# Implode 3 select values into one field error

Tags: php, select, form-submit, implode

I'm currently trying to place 3 select values into one field. I'm trying to do this by imploding the values; however i'm getting an error saying:

> "Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed"

Updated Version

```
<script>
function datepopulate(){
var day = document.getElementById('airdate_day').value;
var month = document.getElementById('airdate_month').value;
var year = document.getElementById('airdate_year').value;

var completedate = day+'-'+month+'-'+year;
document.getelementById('episode_airdate').value = completedate;
return true;
    }
</script>
        <?php
for($i=1910; $i<=2012; $i++)
    $years[]=$i;

    echo '<select id="airdate_year" onChange="javascript:datepopulate();" style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;">';
                        echo '<option value="">' . __("2012" ) . '</option>';
        foreach($years as $year){
                            $selected = '';
                            echo '<option value="' . $year . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $year . '</option>';
                        }
                    echo '</select>';


                    for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
                        $months[]=$i;

                    echo '<select id="airdate_month" onChange="javascript:datepopulate();" style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;">';
                        echo '<option value="">' . __("0" ) . '</option>';
                        foreach($months as $month){
                            $selected = '';
                            echo '<option value="' . $month . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $month . '</option>';
                        }
                    echo '</select>';


                    for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
                        $days[]=$i;

                    echo '<select name="airdate_day" id="airdate_day" onChange="javascript:datepopulate();"  style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;">';
                        echo '<option value="">' . __("10" ) . '</option>';
                        foreach($days as $day){
                            $selected = '';
                            echo '<option value="' . $day . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $day . '</option>';
                        }
                    echo '</select>';
                    ?> 
            <input type="hidden" name="episode_airdate[]" id="episode_airdate[]"  class="airdate regular-text" value="" />
```

Comment: print_r($_POST['episode_airdate']).Is it an array?

Comment: `$date = implode('-', $_POST['episode_airdate']);
                date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['episode_airdate']));` You try to treat it as an array in the `$date` var, then a string in the `date()` function?

Comment: How are you populating your hidden field with Date, Month and Year ? As i guess you want your hidden field to post a complete date you have selected from select box, Am I right? Or Am I right?

Comment: @OMTheEternity Thanks for your help thus far, for some reason I am still having problems. I have uploaded the new codes, if you could take another look please.

Answer (score 1):

Your $_POST['episode_airdate'] is not posted as array here....

Seems you are willing here to generate a date , hence for your ease use below given url for a PHP library of date Picker....

[PHP Date Picker](http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php)

> **UPDATE**

As per your comment on this answer... If you want to populate your hidden field then you have to use the javascript created functions, in which these functions will be called whenever there will be a change in the value of select box, the function will fetch the values from all the three select boxes and implode them in your desired format as DD-MM-YYYY.. and populate the hidden field with this newly created value

below would be your function it is not the tested one.. but you have to do it like this:

First of all make all the id attribute of the select box different say `id='airdate_day'` for day select box, `id='airdate_month'` for month select box and `id='airdate_year'` for year select box

and make the hidden field id as `id='episode_airdate'` and `name='episode_airdate'`

Javascript function:

```
function datepopulate(){
    var day = document.getElementById('airdate_day').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('airdate_month').value;
    var year = document.getElementById('airdate_year').value;

   var completedate = day+'-'+month+'-'+year;
   document.getelementById('episode_airdate').value = completedate;
   return true;
}
```

Now onChange attribute of every select box will call this function as

`<select name='airdate_day' id='airdate_day' onChange='javascript:datepopulate();'>`

and in the similar way other two select box will call the javascript function

And now when the form is posted your `$_POST['episode_airdate']` will contain a complete date, hence you don't have to use `implode()` function in it and can directly apply your `datetime()` function ove the `$_POST['episode_airdate']` variable

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't want to use a plugin, I know it would be more difficult doing it this way but I prefer it. Do you have any suggestions on how to populate the hidden field?

Comment: @Craig Check the latest Updated Answer

Comment: Thank you for everything but i'm still having trouble, the selects and hidden field is inside a table only and not in a form, could this be the reason i'm having difficulties?  i upload the new version  after implementing your codes

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of implode function must be an Array, you give a POST variable.